# How to define listTree so that it runs in linear time?

Tags: haskell, time, tree, fold

```hs
listTree' :: Tree a -> [a]
listTree' t = foldTree f z t []
    where
    f = undefined
    z [] = []
```

Need help solving for f. when I insert `f a b c = a ++ [b] ++  c` I get an error

```hs
data Tree a 
    = Tip
    | Bin (Tree a) a (Tree a)
    deriving (Show, Eq)


foldTree :: (b -> a -> b -> b) -> b -> Tree a -> b
foldTree f z Tip         = z
foldTree f z (Bin l x r) = f (foldTree f z l) x (foldTree f z r)
```

here is foldTree and data type for tree

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: To achieve linear time, I guess you have to use a trick known as "difference lists". That's why `foldTree f z t []` passes an additional `[]` at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to achieve linear time, you should let `foldTree f z t` return a function that takes a list and returns a list.

This means that for `z`, a leaf, we simply return the given list, and we thus do not prepend any value. For `f` we will take the list, call it with the right subtree, then prepend that list with the value of that `Bin` node, and finally call it with the left subtree, so:

```
listTree' :: Tree a -> [a]
listTree' t = foldTree f id t []
    where f x y z ls = x (y: z ls)
```

Here `ls` is thus the list we need to process, `z` is a function to prepend the items of the right subtree to `ls`, `y` is the value stored in that node, and `x` is a function that prepends the items of the left subtree to the list.

We can define `f`, as [@chi says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69859521/how-to-define-listtree-so-that-it-runs-in-linear-time/69859558#comment123488947_69859558) as `f x y z = x . (y:) . z`. We thus first apply the function generated for the right subtree, then prepend the list with `y`, and then run it through the function of the left subtree.

Comment: A nice trick is to pretend that `.` is list concatenation and write `f x y z = x . (y:) . z` which is almost as readable as the simpler but inefficient `++` solution.

Comment: the direction it actually "runs" in is the opposite, left-to-right, because of lazy evaluation. also, you use `z` twice with two different meanings. that's bound to confuse someone.